# Could not find binding files Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, binding, phaser-framework, parceljs

I am losing my mind over this. Its been months since I last touched my project and I finally got the motivation to work on it again. It was working back then but this has been a road block recently. I am losing my mind please help I cant find a fix.

```
> phaser3-parcel-template@1.0.0 start
> parcel src/index.html -p 8000      

C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:126
  err = new Error(
        ^

Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
 → C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\deasync\build\deasync.node
 → C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\deasync\build\Debug\deasync.node
 → C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\deasync\build\Release\deasync.node
 → C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\deasync\out\Debug\deasync.node
 → C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\deasync\Debug\deasync.node
 → C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\deasync\out\Release\deasync.node
 → C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\deasync\Release\deasync.node
 → C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\deasync\build\default\deasync.node
 → C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\deasync\compiled\18.5.0\win32\x64\deasync.node
 → C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\deasync\addon-build\release\install-root\deasync.node
 → C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\deasync\addon-build\debug\install-root\deasync.node
 → C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\deasync\addon-build\default\install-root\deasync.node
 → C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\deasync\lib\binding\node-v108-win32-x64\deasync.node
    at bindings (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:126:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\deasync\index.js:30:31)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1166:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:834:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
    at require (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\utils\syncPromise.js:1:79)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30) {
  tries: [
    'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\parcel-bundler\\node_modules\\deasync\\build\\deasync.node',
    'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\parcel-bundler\\node_modules\\deasync\\build\\Debug\\deasync.node',
    'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\parcel-bundler\\node_modules\\deasync\\build\\Release\\deasync.node',
    'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\parcel-bundler\\node_modules\\deasync\\out\\Debug\\deasync.node',
    'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\parcel-bundler\\node_modules\\deasync\\Debug\\deasync.node',
    'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\parcel-bundler\\node_modules\\deasync\\out\\Release\\deasync.node',
    'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\parcel-bundler\\node_modules\\deasync\\Release\\deasync.node',
    'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\parcel-bundler\\node_modules\\deasync\\build\\default\\deasync.node',
    'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\parcel-bundler\\node_modules\\deasync\\compiled\\18.5.0\\win32\\x64\\deasync.node',
    'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\parcel-bundler\\node_modules\\deasync\\addon-build\\release\\install-root\\deasync.node',
    'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\parcel-bundler\\node_modules\\deasync\\addon-build\\debug\\install-root\\deasync.node',
    'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\parcel-bundler\\node_modules\\deasync\\addon-build\\default\\install-root\\deasync.node',
    'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\parcel-bundler\\node_modules\\deasync\\lib\\binding\\node-v108-win32-x64\\deasync.node'
  ]
}
```

I've tried reinstalling visual studio didnt work. I've tried NPM Fund or updating whatever the console tells me to update doesn't work. I might look like an idiot and that's because i am. Ive tried following instructions online but im probably doing it wrong bc the instructions arent exactly stupid friendly. Please help me like im 5

Comment: this is is mainly a parcel issue. What for nodejs version do you have? which parcel npm package are you using? some versions don't work with eachother, or atleast create problems.

Comment: It says im using version 9.5 with parcel bundler @1.12.5

Comment: Well strange, I just installed the newest node LTS version, downloaded a parcel template from here _(https://github.com/ourcade/phaser3-parcel-template)_ , remove the `package-lock.json` file updated the packages `npm update`, and the application works/opens. I would recommend copy your code into a new version of the template. _(maybe even switch to a more modern template of the official github repository https://github.com/photonstorm?tab=repositories)_

Comment: but I just say this because I'm no parceljs expert